# How to "rebase" branch (without any real commits) in Subversion (limited access to repository)?

Tags: svn, rebase

I have commit access (write permission) to only one branch in Subversion repository.

Unfortunately said branch was created out of trunk some time ago; I'd like to "rebase" it on top of current trunk (current HEAD).  There are no 'real' commits on said branch, only

> created foo branch based on trunk rev2921

Note: I don't have write permissions to anywhere outside said branch.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no commits in the branch, ask the SVN admin to delete it and create a new one; you might spare yourself some pain that way. Alternatively, you can merge all changes from trunk; most of the time that works fine, but certain directory operations can conflict with each other even when you are doing the SVN equivalent of a fast-forward merge, in which case you will have a lot of manual cleanup to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rebase in SVN. You just need to merge from trunk to branch. Go to your working copy (which point to the branch), and do

```
svn merge http://your.server.com/path/to/trunk
```

Then commit.

You should probably read [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/): it contains lots of valuable informataion.